# Member functions for numpy records

Tags: python, numpy

I have to use numpy arrays of records to save RAM and to have fast access. But I want to use member functions on that records. For example,

```
X=ones(3, dtype=dtype([('foo', int), ('bar', float)]))
X[1].incrementFooBar()
```

For ordinary python class,I can make

```
class QQQ:
  ...
  def incrementFooBar(self):
    self.foo+=1
    self.bar+=1
pass
X=[QQQ(),QQQ(),QQQ()]
X[1].incrementFooBar()
```

How can I make something like that, but for numpy records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think there is a way to use member functions on the records in the numpy array like that.  Alternatively, you could very easily construct a function to accomplish the same thing:

```
X=ones(3, dtype=dtype([('foo', int), ('bar', float)]))

def incrementFooBar(X, index):
    X['foo'][index] += 1
    X['bar'][index] += 1

#then instead of "X[1].incrementFooBar()"
incrementFooBar(X, 1)
```

Comment: Technically that's a function.  Method, in python, is a function that is bound to a class instance.  But I agree this is only way to do this.  It isn't easy to add methods to arrays and their elements.